# Como guardar texto en un txt con fwrite en php

Tags: php

En el siguiente ejemplo me guarda en un archivo txt el contenido que deseo, hasta aca funciona perfecto, el problema que el archivo txt me lo crea en formato asci y me guarda el contenido con caracteres raros.

Si me pueden ayudar, super agradecido. Saludos.

```
$file=fopen("1.txt","w+");

fwrite($archivo,"guardar texto? ë ì ?");

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Tal vez te sirva esta inforamcion: http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/generar-archivo-texto-utf-8-con-php-363153/

Comment: Hola gracias lo voy a probar y le comento.

Comment: Sigo con el mimo problema Por ejemplo:
El signo de ¿ me lo guarda en el txt asi Â
El acento me lo guarda asi Ã©

Comment: Ahi probe poniendole el header con el utf-8 y a mi me lo muestra ok, por favor verifica si vos lo ves bien

Comment: la verdad que esta igual. y el archivo te lo guarda en asci o utf-8

Comment: lo pude solucionar, al parecer tenia un problema de cache. desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proba de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

$archivo = fopen("2.txt", "a") or die("Error al crear el txt");

$txt = "guardar texto? ë ì ? ñ ñ"; 

fwrite($archivo,$txt); 

fclose($archivo);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sigo igual, la verdad que no se a que se deba. Se sigue guardando el archivo como asci y no como utf-8

Comment: y el archivo te lo guarda en utf-8 o asci?

Comment: Es que no estoy creando un txt con el codigo, el txt lo cree yo, este codigo solo va lo abre y le pone el texto que le digo adentro, ya si queres que tu codigo cree el txt, lo abra, le ponga el texto y lo cierre hay que meter mas codigo

Comment: de todas formas lo probe de las dos maneras, que ya este creado en utf-8 y que se cree solo.

Comment: al txt lo creo en utf-8 y cuando quiere grabar mi texto me lo pasa a asci.

Comment: Proba el codigo que puse ahora, creo el archivo 2.txt, lo abre, pone el texto y lo cierra, ya si ahi no te funciona no es problema del codigo hay que investigar por otro lado.

Comment: Lo he probado y me guarda el siguiente texto? Ã« Ã¬ ? Ã± Ã±guardar texto? Ã« Ã¬ ? Ã± Ã± .

Comment: Mire lo pude solucionar, al parecer tenia un problema de cache. desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo. saludos.

Answer (score 1):

¿Los símbolos extraños salen cuando utilizas acentos o Ñ?

Si es así es por el formato, debes setearlo en `UTF-8`.

Te recomiendo editar la pregunta para proporcionar mas detalles.

Comment: Hola le comento, me guarda bien el texto, pero con extraños simbolos en lo que se refiere a acentos y signos de interrogacion. Cuando lo abro e intento ver en que formato esta me indica que esta en asci y no en utf-8.

Comment: Tendrias que eliminar esta respuesta y ponerla como comentario al problema que plantea el usuario, sino es muy probable que te califiquen esta respuesta en negativo porque no esta aportando una respuesta al problema

Comment: Sigo con el mimo problema Por ejemplo:
El signo de ¿ me lo guarda en el txt asi Â
El acento me lo guarda asi Ã©

Comment: la zona de respuestas no es espacio para hacer preguntas al OP respecto a su cuestión, así que por favor edítala dejando únicamente una respuesta a su problema